# NativeScript error using [(ngModel)]

Tags: data-binding, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

I'm starting an app using Nativescript and I still don't know so much this framework. I'm trying to make a page to create an user account and I have a form where you have to write your email and password. The problem is that I need to catch the strings that the user write and for this I use [(ngModel)], but I have an error. I have imported the **NativeScriptFormsModule** in my app.module.ts and this gets my an error.

Here is my **create.user.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { RouterExtensions } from 'nativescript-angular/router';

import firebase = require('nativescript-plugin-firebase');

@Component({
    selector:'create-user',
    template:`
                <StackLayout>
                    <Label class="titulo" text="Create User"></Label>
                    <TextField hint="Email" keyboardType="text" [(ngModel)]="email"
                        autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                    <TextField hint="Password" secure="true" [(ngModel)]="password"
                        autocorrect="false" autocapitalizationType="none"></TextField>
                    <Button class="submit-botton" (tap)="create()" text="Crear usuario"></Button>
                </StackLayout>
        `,
    styleUrls:['login/login.component.css']
})
export class CreateUserComponent{

    email:string;
    password:string;

    constructor(private routerExt: RouterExtensions ){}

        create(){
            firebase.createUser({
                email:this.email,
                password: this.password

            }).then(
                (result)=>{

                    this.routerExt.navigate(["/chatListado"],{
                        transition:{
                            name: "flip",
                            duration:500,
                            curve:"linear"
                        }
                    });
                    console.log("User Created");
                },
                (errorMessage)=>{
                    alert('error: ' + errorMessage);
                }
            );

        }
}
```

And this is the error I have when I start the app:

> JS: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: No value accessor for
>   form control with unspecified name attribute JS: Error: No value
>   accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute JS: at
>   _throwError (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1838:11)
>   [angular] JS: at setUpControl
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:1751:9)
>   [angular] JS: at NgModel._setUpStandalone
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4320:9)
>   [angular] JS: at NgModel._setUpControl
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4306:37)
>   [angular] JS: at NgModel.ngOnChanges
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js:4237:18)
>   [angular] JS: at checkAndUpdateDirectiveInline
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:10715:19)
>   [angular] JS: at checkAndUpdateNodeInline
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12097:17)
>   [angular] JS: at checkAndUpdateNode
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12065:16)
>   [angular] JS: at debugCheckAndUpdateNode
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12694:59)
>   [angular] JS: at debugCheckDirectivesFn
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12635:13)
>   [angular] JS: at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]
>   (ng:///AppModule/LoginComponent.ngfactory.js:363:5) [angular] JS: at
>   Object.debugUpdateDirectives [as updateDirectives]
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12620:21)
>   [angular] JS: at checkAndUpdateView
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12032:14)
>   [angular] JS: at callViewAction
>   (file:///data/data/com.Mystory.android/files/app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:12347:17)
>   [angular]

Comment: Import the `NativeScriptFormsModule` in your main app.component.ts and it should work

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have done the following in your module file (quoted from docs.nativescript.org)

> Before we can use the ngModel directive in a two-way data binding, we
>   must import the NativeScriptFormsModule and add it to the Angular
>   module's imports list:

```
import {NativeScriptFormsModule} from "nativescript-angular/forms"
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptRouterModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule, // RIGHT HERE
    ],
})
```